# regex find two of the same kind which share a matched character

Tags: regex

I have a regex:

```
/(?:(?:\b|_)([a-z][a-z])(?:\b|_))/gi
```

and a string:

```
of  Us_AR.xyz
```

the regex matches `of` and `Us` but I also need `AR`.
Seems the `_` has been 'used' to match the `Us` and so is not available for matching with `AR`?

Ho do I fix this?

Comment: Can you show us more sample data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use negative look ahead:

[`/(?:[^a-z]|^)([a-z]{2})(?![a-z])/gi`](https://regex101.com/r/sZ29tD/1)

Look behind is not possible in JS, so you should not treat what is matched in the first non-capturing group, only what is captured in the only *capturing* group.

- `[^a-z]|^`: matches a non-letter or the start of the string (`^`)
- `[a-z]{2}`: matches 2 letters
- `(?![a-z])`: requires that there is no letter following, but does not capture it.

The first expression is put in `(?:  )`, so it is not available as a capture group. The second expression is put in `(  )` so you can reference it.

Comment: this works for me...  Thankyou, now I've just got to try to understand it :).

Comment: I added a small breakdown.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to extract the words on either side of an underscore at the start of your string, then why not use the following pattern:

```
([A-Z]+)\s+([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)
```

The three matches you want would be available in the first through third capture groups.

```js
var input = "of    Us_AR.xyz";
var pattern = /([A-Z]+)\s+([A-Z]+)_([A-Z]+)/gi;
var match = pattern.exec(input);
console.log(match[1]);
console.log(match[2]);
console.log(match[3]);
```

Comment: The input contains "of " as well.

Comment: @userunknown I am not sure if my answer is what the OP wants, but it seems to work now, at least for the exact input in the OP.